# Changing the sort_id of other entries after deleting one entry PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with sort_id (not the main id) which manages the sorting through jquery sortables.
I also have a delete method that deletes the entry through its sort_id.
After deleting the entry I want the entries below that entry (in sort_id) order to be rearranged and replace the missing the sort_id.
So If I had sort_id entries 1 2 3 4 5 and I deleted 1 then it would be left as 2 3 4 5, this would give me error as "1" is missing, so I'll need the 2 3 4 and 5 to decrement back to 1 2 3 4.

This is my delete function

```html
   public function deleteRank(Request $request, $id){
        $this->validate($request,[
           'rankid' => 'required',
        ]);

        rank::where('rankid',$request->get('rankid'))->delete();

        return redirect()->route('rankeditor');
    }
```

Comment: you could decrement every `sort_id` that is higher than the one you are deleting

Comment: how would I do that in eloquent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked by using decrement for rank_id entries greater than the one deleted

```
 rank::where('rankid','>',$request->get('rankid'))->decrement('rankid');
```